# Create Azure AD user with ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

Is there a way for an ARM template used in automation to create an Azure AD user account for a human to use to log in to the Azure Portal with a password?

If so, what is the minimal code for an ARM template to accomplish this?

AWS makes this easy using CloudFormation.  But so far my research about how to do this with ARM templates has not produced any results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Azure Resource Manager (i.e., what ARM stands for) is used to manage (as the name suggests) Azure Resources only. However, Microsoft decided, that every kind of user accounts (except managed Identities, but let's ignore them for know) are only and fully managed by Azure AD (or Entra ID), which is another product. Eventually, they are coupled and the users managed in Azure AD can be used in Azure (ARM), but still reside in Azure AD. Unfortunately, the naming is quite confusing IMHO. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/overview) if you want to learn more about what all falls under the domain of ARM.

So what you are looking for is a way to manage Azure AD resource in code, which is given by the Graph API. The correct API to create users is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) if you need further details, but the query eventually is:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
Body:
{
    "accountEnabled": true,
    "city": "Seattle",
    "country": "United States",
    "department": "Sales & Marketing",
    "displayName": "Melissa Darrow",
    "givenName": "Melissa",
    "jobTitle": "Marketing Director",
    "mailNickname": "MelissaD",
    "passwordPolicies": "DisablePasswordExpiration",
    "passwordProfile": {
        "password": "76734553-24af-87e1-d3c5-a1fb1ecdb305",
        "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": false
    },
    "officeLocation": "131/1105",
    "postalCode": "98052",
    "preferredLanguage": "en-US",
    "state": "WA",
    "streetAddress": "9256 Towne Center Dr., Suite 400",
    "surname": "Darrow",
    "mobilePhone": "+1 206 555 0110",
    "usageLocation": "US",
    "userPrincipalName": "MelissaD@{domain}"
}
Request Header:
Authentication (bearer)
Content-type application/json
```

Additionally, Microsoft offers the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) where you can play around with these APIs for Azure AD.

P.S.: Another common point of confusion is the role management. As Azure AD and Azure (ARM) are two products, they have different role managements and different permissions. To not fall for common problems, you may like this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/rbac-and-directory-admin-roles)